# Does the general density theorem imply the closing lemma?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Two fundamental results in the theory of differentiable dynamical systems are the:

*General density theorem:*

For a $C^1$-generic diffeomorphism of a closed manifold, the periodic points are dense in the nonwandering set.

and the

*Closing lemma*:

Given a nonwandering point $p$ of a diffeomorphism $f$ of a closed manifold, one can find a $C^1$-small perturbation of $f$ so that $p$ is a periodic point.

I am not an expert in this field, but I normally think of the first theorem as of more intrinsic interest, and the second as a tool used to prove the first.  But is it obvious that the first implies the second?